# How to add another textfield to UISearchController when focus is on Search Bar?

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uisearchdisplaycontroller, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to add another textfield for a 'Location' input to a UISearchController when the user focuses on the Search Bar, just below the Search Bar on the navigation bar.

Example of what I have and where I'd like it to go:

[image]

I've tried something like this, which doesn't work:

```
var searchController: UISearchController!

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    var myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200.00, height: 40.00))
    myTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    myTextField.text = "Location"
    myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
    searchController.view.addSubview(myTextField)
}
```

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Can you add more code. I want to know how you handle it.

Answer (score 4):

Don't know whether you found your answer or not. Let me suggest my solution.

Nothing wrong in your code. It works fine. But the reason why it doesn't show is , when you click in the search bar `func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar)` has no effect on it because you might forget to set the delegate for the search bar.

I tried your code and after setting the delegate it just works fine. Also it hides behind the navbar as the Y position is 0. The solution is,

1. Add the `UISearchBarDelegate` to your class
2. In `viewDidLoad()`

   ```
     override func viewDidLoad(){
       super.viewDidLoad()
       searchcontroller.searchbar.delegate = self
       }
   ```
3. In `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing`

   ```
      func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {           

       var myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: searchController.searchBar.frame.height + 20, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 40.00))
       myTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
       myTextField.text = "Location"
       myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
       searchController.view.addSubview(myTextField)
   }
   ```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> **Try like This:**
>
> you just create a custom NavigationBar add your text field to that and override the SearchController Delegate Methods

try it may works .